# Why aren't Swift Strings bridged to NSString in a Dictionary when Foundation is imported?

Tags: swift, swift3, anyobject

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38701761/2415822) on the question [Value of type 'String' does not conform to expected dictionary value type 'AnyObject'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38701044/2415822), importing Foundation should implicitly bridge a Swift `String` struct to `NSString`, so it can be used in `[String : AnyObject]` dictionaries.  But I'm not seeing that behavior in Xcode 8/Swift 3:

```
import Foundation
let dict: [String : AnyObject] = ["hello" : "world"] // Value of type 'String' does not conform to expected dictionary value type 'AnyObject'
```

Are Swift Strings no longer implicitly bridged to `NSString`?  Are my only options to cast my `String` value as `AnyObject` or `NSString`, or use a `[String : Any]` dictionary type instead?

Comment: The *implicit* bridging between Swift and Foundation types was removed in Swift 3: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0072-eliminate-implicit-bridging-conversions.md.

Comment: @MartinR ah ok.  So my only options are to cast or use `Any`?  Meh, these changes will take some getting used to...